# Java : Cookie lost using HttpURLConnection

Tags: java, url, session-cookies, httpurlconnection

I have this browser class:

```
public class browser{

    private List<String> cookies;
    private HttpURLConnection conn;
<....>
public String GetPageContent(String url) throws Exception {

        URL obj = new URL(url);
        conn = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();

        // default is GET
        conn.setRequestMethod("GET");

        conn.setUseCaches(false);

        // act like a browser
        conn.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", USER_AGENT);
        conn.setRequestProperty("Accept",
                "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Accept-Language",
                "en-GB,en;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,ro;q=0.4,fr;q=0.2");
        if (cookies != null) {
            for (String cookie : this.cookies) {
                conn.addRequestProperty("Cookie", cookie.split(";", 1)[0]);
            }
            System.out.println(cookies);
        }
        int responseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
        System.out.println("\nSending 'GET' request to URL : " + url);
        System.out.println("Response Code : " + responseCode);

        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                conn.getInputStream()));
        String inputLine;
        StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
            response.append(inputLine);
        }
        in.close();

        // Get the response cookies
        setCookies(conn.getHeaderFields().get("Set-Cookie"));

        return response.toString();

    }
```

<...>

```
public List<String> getCookies() {
    return cookies;
}

public void setCookies(List<String> cookies) {
    this.cookies = cookies;
}
```

Everything is fine if all my request comes from MainApp:

```
public class main_program {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Browser br = new Browser();
            Check_List users = new Check_List ();
            br.GetPageContent(//some url) >> see the cookies and retrives the url fine
```

but when I do something like this in my main program:

```
users.getList()
```

which is a another class in the same package that calls GetPageContent method from Browser class the things gets strange: most of the request don't have cookies attached.
The class looks like this:

```
public class Check_List {
    private HashMap<String, String> dictionar = new HashMap<String, String>();

    public void getList(HashMap dictionar) {
        http_handler webpage = new http_handler();
    try {
            Iterator it = dictionar.entrySet().iterator();
            while (it.hasNext()) {
                Map.Entry pairs = (Map.Entry) it.next();
                System.out.println(pairs.getKey() + " = " + pairs.getValue());
                webpage.GetPageContent("http://example.com/profile.php?id="+pairs.getKey()+"&actionid=15");
                System.out.println("I'am on user: " + pairs.getValue());
```

Comment: Why do you want to re-invent the wheel? If you need a browser class use Apache commons HTTP, it has already a working cookie management system integrated.

Comment: Can you point out on what code from Apache you are referring? Thanks

Comment: @MikeS_45 As a result of Googling, [this](http://hc.apache.org).